# Kafka SASL Authentication mechanism using OAuthBearer?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, apache-kafka, sasl

Can anyone help me to write JAAS conf files and Handler classes for Authentication using SASL/OAUTHBEARER?

And also what is the meaning of this option in JAAS file which is configured in kafka documentation?

```
unsecuredLoginStringClaim_sub="admin";
```

Answer (score 1):

For SASL/OAUTHBEARER the JAAS config file will be, at least:

```
KafkaServer {
   org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required ;
};
```

Other params will be used by your implementation of the interface *AuthenticateCallbackHandler* that can receive other parameters like your OAuth server host, grant type or other information that you need to do the login flow. The option *unsecuredLoginStringClaim_sub="admin"* is one of these parameters.

If you need to setup and test a Kafka broker with this SASL mechanism, you can see this article. 
https://medium.com/@jairsjunior/how-to-setup-oauth2-mechanism-to-a-kafka-broker-e42e72839fe

Answer (score 0):

See the Javadoc at https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/oauthbearer/OAuthBearerLoginModule.java for an explanation of `unsecuredLoginStringClaim_sub="admin"` -- that is an option that is recognized by the default unsecured callback handlers you get out-of-the-box.